# Does LINQ replace regex in all cases

Tags: c#, regex, linq, programming-languages

Can a LINQ expression replace all cases where regex would have previously been used?

In other words; does a regex exist that can not be represented by a LINQ query?

Comment: With apples, can we completely do without oranges?

Comment: Does a regex exist that **can** be represented by a LINQ query?

Comment: This sounds like a proof by contradiction. I would challenge someone to post a RegEx that *can't* be written using a LINQ statement just to get an easy answer on this question. =)

Comment: @Rick: Are you kidding me? You can perform pattern matching with LINQ, you can perform replacement, you can do just about anything you wish. At the end of the day it makes you think about all data - but specifically strings - as arrays of characters that can be queried.

Comment: PS: I am no genius but I have been able to grasp concepts like threads, generics, cpu architectures, gravity, stars, fusion and fission but regex remains completely alien to me. Regex is a tool written by Satan to keep programmers in a constant state of hell.

Comment: @Maxim: A regex pattern is context-sensitive; a LINQ query is context-insensitive.  All non-trivial regex patterns are not representable in LINQ.

Comment: I don't see how can linq be used as regexp - after it passed an item it forgets about it.

Comment: @maxim offtopic, but if you can really understand so many nuanced math and compsci topics, and really do not understand regex, then i suggest you implement your own Regex engine in the language of your choice... RE's are well defined mathematically, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex#Formal_language_theory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably possible to craft a LINQ expression for any given regular expression, but doing so will likely be unreasonable in many cases. Even if you eliminate things like backreferences, regular expressions can be arbitrarily complex. The beauty of regular expressions (and I find it somewhat surprising that I use the term "beauty" to describe regex) is that it's a compact and expressive, but very narrowly focused tool for pattern matching in strings.

LINQ, on the other hand, is a very expressive general purpose tool.

Take a simple regular expression like `(ab)+([0-9^%#@-.,]{1,5})ab[0-9]$`. Can you write a LINQ expression for that? If you can, it's going to be quite verbose--certainly much more verbose than the regex, and you'll have to include code that gets the capture groups. Not only do you have to say if the string matches the expression, but you have to say where the match starts, how long it is, etc. I suspect it's possible, but you're going to write a whole lot of custom code to do it.

I'm not a huge fan of the regex, but it does have its place. Sometimes it really is the right tool for the job. I'd jump at the chance to replace it with something better, but LINQ sure isn't it.

Answer (score 4):

I have never thought that about LINQ in that way.  Regex is a very comprehensive language for text matching, whereas LINQ is query language.  LINQ does have predicates to do matching, but is not itself a text matching tool.  I would not recommend using LINQ in place of Regex.  What are your intentions in this case.

Comment: I have no specific goal in mind - just wondering - but I don't see why LINQ can't be used in place of regex given how much easier it is to write and how much clearer the intention is. Having said that, I'm not sure of the performance issues that may arise.

Comment: One thing to consider is that LINQ is not much more than a for/foreach loop that will perform some predicate or aggregate operation and then yield a collection of the results.  I think in LINQ's case, the performance of a compiled regex statement will be unimaginably faster than any LINQ statement could be.  I don't think that I can recommend that practice, although it might be fun, because I love LINQ.

Comment: I think it would make you cry when you see how bad it will be.  Of course, with a mundane example they will be the same, but if you use a hairy regex and duplicate that in LINQ you will see.  If you take the Regex for the RFC 822 (email), I think you would be hard pressed to replicate that in LINQ.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html:      (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])

Comment: Hahaha, your link doesnt work but I know the regex you're talking about... Lets be honest though, that regex is probably not correct (I dont think many programmers in the world could explain it) and I would argue you can perform *the function* of the regex through LINQ either way.

Comment: Whoops. Sorry didnt see the second post. PS: I remember it being much bigger no?

Comment: I have used this regex in production, and no it does work to the letter, but it is not reasonable.  If I remember it allows for some crazy stuff, but it does match the RFC.  You are right though, I double there is anyone who could verbally decompose this junk :)   Here is the link:http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: I was talking about this one... Check it out: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: Yikes, that doesn't even look real :)  I cannot even imagine the time that it took to create that let alone test it.

Comment: Understatement of the century: "somewhat pushes the limits of what it is sensible to do with regular expressions" lol

Comment: Yuck makes a good point, I am not sure that you can do negative lookaheads and stuff like that in LINQ.  So even with reasonable Regex, there could easily be things that LINQ simply cannot match on.

Answer (score 4):

"In other words; does a regex exist that can not be represented by a LINQ query?"

No.

```
var pattern = "anypattern";
string input = "someInput";
var q = input.Any(c => new Regex(pattern).IsMatch(input));
```

:)

Comment: Can a male cow make milk? Yes, glue a female cow to it and milk it.

Comment: Cheater, cheater, pumpkin eater. :-)

Comment: I think if you are trying to do this, you should constrain yourself to not using regex in the LINQ.  You should stick to native operators or else you really arent proving anything.

Comment: @hivie7510, my point was that of course you *can* do anything a regex can do with a LINQ expression, but at what point do you say: "Well, technically yes you are still using LINQ but you're not accomplishing what you want through LINQ per se, but through helper functions, etc." After all, in the end, LINQ is simply syntactic sugar. Very sweet sugar to be sure, but it's just that. See http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx for an example of how to use "LINQ" in .NET 2.0

Comment: Right on, I misunderstood your intent, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Does [Fluent Regex](http://flimflan.com/blog/ReadableRegularExpressions.aspx) count? Fluent Regex turns this:

```
Regex socialSecurityNumberCheck = new Regex(@"^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$");
```

into this:

```
Regex socialSecurityNumberCheck = new Regex(Pattern.With.AtBeginning
    .Digit.Repeat.Exactly(3)
    .Literal("-").Repeat.Optional
    .Digit.Repeat.Exactly(2)
    .Literal("-").Repeat.Optional
    .Digit.Repeat.Exactly(4)
    .AtEnd);
```

If so, the answer is **yes!**

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, considering Fluent Regex is not LINQ and therefore does not count.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're going to run into is without `RegEx`, what tools do you have left for pattern matching? LINQ is great for making set-based and iterative algorithms easier to read, but it can't do pattern matching on its own. You're going to end up stuck using the `String` library which is, sadly, less expressive than `RegEx` and almost certainly not as quick.